# $\neg \forall x \in V[v \cdot x=0$ iff $w \cdot x=0]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $V=F^n$ for some field $F$. Let $\cdot$ be the dot product $(v_1,...,v_n)\cdot(w_1,...,w_n)=v_1w_1+...=v_nw_n$.

Now fix two vectors $\{v,w\}$ and assume they are linearly independent. My question is, will we necessarily have $\neg \forall x \in V[v \cdot x=0$ iff $w \cdot x=0]$?

I see that the assumption ensures $n \geq 2$. Intuitively, I want to say "yes."

To prove the above, all that is necessary is to find explicitly some vector $x$ such that one of the dot products is zero and the other nonzero.

Comment: "In $\mathbb{R}^n$, the only vector orthogonal to two linearly independent vectors is the zero vector": this statement is incorrect.  However, if $x$ is perpendicular to two linearly independent vectors, then it must lie in the orthogonal complement of their span.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You're right, that works for $\mathbb{R}^2$ but not for general $n$. I will fix my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes: if $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent, then it cannot be the case that $v \cdot x = 0 \iff w \cdot x = 0$.

To see that this is the case, it suffices to consider the linear map $T:F^n \to F^2$ defined by 
$$
T(v) = (v \cdot x, w \cdot x).
$$
The set of $x$ satisfying $v \cdot x = 0$ has dimension $n-1$ by the rank-nullity theorem.  However, if $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent, then the matrix representing the transformation $T$ with respect to the usual basis has linearly independent rows, which means that $T$ has rank $2$.  It follows by the rank-nullity theorem that the set of $x$ satisfying $v \cdot x = w \cdot x = 0$ has dimension $n-2$.

Since $\{x: v \cdot x = 0\}$ and $\{x:v \cdot x = w \cdot x = 0\}$ have different dimensions, they must be distinct sets.  The conclusion follows.

---

A similar approach:

Let $f_1(x) = v \cdot x$, $f_2(x) = w \cdot x$. Since $f_1$ is non-zero, there exists an $x \in X$ with $f_1(x) \neq 0$.  Define $\alpha = f_2(x)/f_1(x)$.

By linear independence, we have $f_2 \neq \alpha f_1$.  So, there exists a $y \in X$ such that
$$
f_2(y) \neq \alpha f_1(y) \implies f_2(y) \neq [f_2(x)/f_1(x)]f_1(y) \implies
f_1(x)f_2(y) - f_1(x)f_2(y) \neq 0
$$
We note that $y$ cannot be a multiple of $x$, and neither $x$ nor $y$ are zero.  Now, consider the restriction of the map $(f_1,f_2):X \to F^2$ to the span of the vectors $\{x,y\}$.  We can represent this map as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
f_1(ax+by)\\f_2(ax + by)
\end{bmatrix} =
M \begin{bmatrix}
a\\b
\end{bmatrix} :=
\begin{bmatrix}
f_1(x) & f_1(y)\\
f_2(x) & f_2(y)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for arbitrary coefficients $a,b \in F$. By our computation above, $\det(M) \neq 0$, so that $M$ is non-singular.  Thus, we may select the $a,b$ satisfying
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b
\end{bmatrix} = 
M^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
And find that we have $f_1(ax + by) = 1$, while $f_2(ax + by) = 0$.  Thus, $ax + by \in \ker(f_2) \setminus \ker(f_1)$.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without matrix representations? I am trying to prove a lemma for a homework problem from Dummit and Foote Chapter 4, and the linear algebra stuff comes later in the book and I'm not sure my instructor would approve.

Comment: In particular, how would one show that $T$ is surjective without using matrices? (I think I can fill in the other steps by considering $T$ as a group homomorphism and using the First Isomorphism Theorem.)

Comment: One approach would be to note that the adjoint of $T$ is injective

Comment: But, if I recall, the adjoint is defined in terms of matrix representations (at least in Artin).

Comment: Not necessarily.  In any cases, I've included another proof adapted from an old homework assignment that only nominally uses matrices.

Comment: You could also define the adjoint relative to a bilinear form (in this case, $\langle x, y \rangle = x \cdot y$) by saying that
$$
\langle Tx, y \rangle = \langle x, T^*y \rangle
$$
for all $x,y$.

Comment: Thank you, this is more what I was looking for! By the way, what are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Arbitrary coefficients; I added some explanation there.

Comment: You might find it interesting that the assignment was geared towards the infinite dimensional setting.  You'll notice that, unlike my first proof, my second proof does not use the fact that $F^n$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: Oh! That's pretty cool! (By the way, I think there's a typo in the 2x2 matrix.)

Comment: Well spotted, thanks